# I'm trying to download a pdf file from a node server to a react client but when I open it, it shows blank

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm just reading the data from the file from node and sending the content type as "application/pdf".

My node version is 10.

serverside.js:

```
var file = path.join(__dirname,'Rajesh.pdf');
fs.readFile(file, function(err, data){
    res.contentType("application/pdf");
    res.send(data)
})
```

clientside.js:

```
axios.get('/api/downloadcv')
      .then(res => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data]
          ,{type: "application/pdf"}))
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'resume.pdf');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
      })
```

The pdf is getting downloaded but it shows nothing, when I opened it with Vs Code    it showed me something like this:

`%PDF-1.4
%äüöß
2 0 obj
<</Length 3 0 R/Filter/FlateDecode>>
stream
x��\K�d�m������n�u�F���Ad�d`

Comment: Why you putting the pdf contents on the dom? A simple open in new window or download attribute would do the same

Answer (score 18):

Just add `responseType` as header with value `arraybuffer`. You should be good to go.

`axios.get('/api/downloadcv', {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})`

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Wow... Thanks a bunch

Comment: Why does no one say this as the answer. I have been working on this whole day.

Comment: You saved my life bro, having wasting time about 12 hours.

Comment: you save the day

Comment: It's a shame this answer isn't more prominent in search engines. This is all you need to set when downloading pdf blobs, and then you can use fs.writeFileSync to add it to the file system.